# Sum - geometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-series

I have series a + 2(1-a)a + 3 (1-a) (1-a)a + 4 (1-a)(1-a)a + … 
Does this series have a common ratio? How can I calculate sum and average?

Comment: Are you sure about that last term?

Comment: @baskon1 Please type your answer properly before asking a question.

Comment: @baskon1 I rolled back your question. If you want to ask the updated question, you can ask a new question to avoid making older answers useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean $4(1-a)(1-a)(1-a)a$ for your last-listed term, here's a way we can go:

First, observe that each term can be written as $$-a\cdot\frac{d}{da}\left[(1-a)^n\right]$$ for some positive integer $n,$ so that our series can be rewritten in the form $$-a\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{d}{da}\left[(1-a)^n\right],$$ and in fact, as $$-a\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{d}{da}\left[(1-a)^n\right].$$ Do you see why? Now, by power series derivative properties, we may rewrite that as $$-a\frac{d}{da}\left[\sum_{n=0}^\infty(1-a)^n\right].$$ Using the closed form of geometric series sums, we have for $|1-a|<1$ that $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(1-a)^n=\frac{1}{1-(1-a)}=\frac{1}{a},$$ and so our series becomes $$-a\frac{d}{da}\left[\frac1a\right]=-a\cdot-\frac1{a^2}=\frac1a.$$

---

As for the common ratio question: No. You can verify this by seeing that the second term is $2(1-a)$ times the first, while the third term is $\frac32(1-a)$ times the second. This can only be equal if $a=1,$ in which case our series becomes $1+0+0+0+0....$

As for average: I'm not at all sure what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

We have:

$$a+
\left\{ 
\begin{aligned}
(1-a) + (1-a)^2 + (1-a)^3 + \cdots \\ 
(1-a) + (1-a)^2 + (1-a)^3 + \cdots \\ 
(1-a)^2 + (1-a)^3 + \cdots  \\ 
(1-a)^3 + \cdots  \\ 
\end{aligned}
\right. 
$$

This is:
$$\left(a + \frac{1-a}{1-(1-a)} \right) + \frac{1-a}{1-(1-a)}+\frac{(1-a)^2}{1-(1-a)} + \frac{(1-a)^3}{1-(1-a)}  + \cdots $$

which is another geometric series:

$$\left(a + \frac{1-a}{1-(1-a)} \right) + \frac{1}{a} \cdot\frac{1-a}{1-(1-a)}$$
$$=a + \frac{1-a}{a} + \frac{1}{a} \cdot \frac{1-a}{a}$$
$$= \frac{(a^2)+(a-a^2)+(1-a^2)}{a^2}$$
$$= \frac{-a^2+a+1}{a^2}$$
$$=-1 + \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{a^2}$$

Comment: Don't forget that the terms with $(1-a)$ as a factor must also be multiplied by $a.$

Comment: @CameronBuie The question changed after I wrote my answer.

Comment: Ah! I should've checked the time stamps.